# Django:The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a project where admin can assign team to manager. But it is not working and i have no idea how it will work. Because it is raising an error saying "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."

Here is my model.py

```
class manager(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
designation = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Meta:
    permissions = [
        ("edit_task", "can edit the task"),
    ]
```

here is my views.py file for the teams of manager

```
@login_required (login_url= 'have the url where it will go')
@permission_required('have the permission that is assigned by me')
def supervisor(request):
return render(request, 'manager/index-3.html')

def supervisor_team(request):
print(request.user.email)
email=request.user.email
obj= Create_Team.objects.filter(status='Accept', 
managers=manager.objects.filter(user__email=email))
return render(request, "manager/accept_team.html", {"object": obj})
```

here is my template

```
<div class="body table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>S No.</th>
                                    <th>COMPANY NAME</th>
                                    <th>TEAM MEMBER</th>
                                    <th>EMAIL</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                    {%for object in team%}
                                <tr>
                                        <form id="form_id" method="POST" action = "#">
                                            {% csrf_token %}

                                    <th scope="row"> {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                                    <td>{{object.company_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.team_member}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.email}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                </tr>

                                {% endfor %}

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

I have no idea where i am wrong.[image: here is the image of the error]

Comment: Please share your `Create_Team` model. I guess you are passing queryset of `manager` but need to pass one instance of manager`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

```
obj= Create_Team.objects.filter(status='Accept', 
managers=manager.objects.filter(user__email=email))
```

if you want to filter by one manager you have to use `get` instead of `filter`:

```
obj= Create_Team.objects.filter(status='Accept', 
managers=manager.objects.get(user__email=email))
```

But if you want to filter by several managers you need to use `__in`:

```
obj= Create_Team.objects.filter(status='Accept', 
managers__in=manager.objects.filter(user__email=email))
```

Also you are passing `{"object": obj})` to template but in templare you are trying to iterate over `team`. So change it to pass `team` variable:

```
return render(request, "manager/accept_team.html", {"team": obj})
```

Comment: yes it works for me but i have an another problem that the teams is not showing in the UI

Comment: So please add your template as well here. And print `obj` before rendering in order to check if it's empty or not.

Comment: teams which are given to manager that is not showing in the frontend

Comment: i have added my template can you please help me

Comment: What if i change that team into object in my template

Comment: Yes, you can change it as well. Like `{% for obj in object %}` But you would need to change every attribute as well like `{{obj.email}}` .