# The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing and

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to get or create an object when a form is save

**My view**

```
@login_required
def index(request, log_id):
    log = get_object_or_404(LogBook, pk=log_id)
    logmessages = LogMessage.objects.filter(logbook=log_id)
    logbook = LogBook.objects.get_or_create(logmessages=logmessages)
    form = CreateLogMessage(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            logbook.done_status = False
            logbook.save()            
            instance.save()
```

My models :

```
class LogMessage(models.Model):
  logbook = models.ForeignKey(LogBook)

class LogDone(models.Model):
  logmessage = models.ForeignKey(LogMessage)
  done_status = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Status")
```

I tried several answers from SO :
[Django:The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150224/djangothe-queryset-value-for-an-exact-lookup-must-be-limited-to-one-result-usin) but it returns another error

> get() returned more than one LogMessage -- it returned 8!

This one [The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing-Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431810/the-queryset-value-for-an-exact-lookup-must-be-limited-to-one-result-using-slici) return again, a different error

> 'int' object has no attribute 'all'

So i am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: change instance.save()  to form.save() (you have no instance variable)

Comment: i beleive `get_or_create` is expecting a logmessage instance not a logmessage queryset.

Comment: I tried both and none is wokring